# query: how to set an image and text to accupy the same space in an <li> element

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a gallery page with a few images.

I've decided to contain my images in an `<li>` element.
html:

```
<div class="gallery-container">
        <ul class="gallery">
            <li class="image"><img src="./images/dungeon.jpg" alt="image of the game">1</li>
            <li class="image"><img src="./images/gallery-background2.jpg" alt="image of the game"></li>
            <li class="image"><img src="./images/html-background-for-gallery.webp" alt="image of the game"></li>
            <li class="image"><img src="./images/navbackground.jpg" alt="image of the game"></li>
            <li class="image"><img src="./images/nsv-bsckground2.jpg" alt="image of the game"></li>
            <li class="image"><img src="./images/shrine.jpg" alt="image of the game"></li>
            <li class="image"><img src="./images/waterfall.jpg" alt="image of the game"></li>
            <li class="image"><img src="./images/city-center.jpg" alt="image of the game"></li>
            <li class="image"><img src="./images/elven-trials.jpg" alt="image of the game"></li>
            <li class="image"><img src="./images/huge-spider.jpg" alt="image of the game"></li>
            <li class="image"><img src="./images/hell-fire.jpg" alt="image of the game"></li>
            <li class="image"><img src="./images/hydrosophic-chaos.jpg" alt="image of the game"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I am required to have the name of the image appear on hover, thus I'm thinking using `positioning` of either text or `img` for that purpose. but what ever I tried didn't seem to work, on top of that I'm not particularly fluent in `positioning`.

css:

```
.gallery-container {
  border: 2px black solid;
}
.gallery {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}
.gallery li {
  max-width: 40%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em 0.5em;
  max-width: 90%;
}
```

I'm looking for ways to make the image contained in an `<li>` element to cover the text without breaking the current layout of the page, preferably the text should be at the center of `<li>` element (`text-align: center;` would probably do the trick after the positioning issue is sorted).
There is more to the `css` and `html` ask for the full code of you think its necessary.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use `position` property then this can be done with `display: grid` by making it's children occupy the same row -- this is easier for paint calculations than positioning an element as well

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box } body { color: white; font: 16px sans-serif; margin: 0 }

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1.5rem;

  margin: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  list-style: none;
}

/* Make <li> a grid and place children in center */
.image {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
/* Make grid children occupy the same space */
.image > * { grid-area: 1/1/-1/-1 }

.image > img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}



/* For visual styling only -- does not affect layout */
.gallery {
  border: 2px black solid;
  margin: 1.5rem auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.image {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.25), 0 2px 4px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.25);
  border-radius: .375em;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(1) rotate(0);
  transition: box-shadow 250ms ease-in-out, transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.image > img {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.image > div {
  background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
  border-radius: 0.375em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  transform: translateY(-3em) scale(0) rotate(0);
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.image:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.25), 0 4px 6px -4px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.25);
  z-index: 1;
}
.image:nth-child(odd):hover { transform: scale(1.075) rotate(-2deg) }
.image:nth-child(even):hover { transform: scale(1.075) rotate(2deg) }
.image:hover > img { opacity: 0.75 }
.image:nth-child(odd):hover > div { transform: translateY(0) scale(1.125) rotate(-360deg) }
.image:nth-child(even):hover > div { transform: translateY(0) scale(1.125) rotate(360deg) }
```

```html
<ul class="gallery">
  <li class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=1" alt="random image">
    <div>overlay 1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=2" alt="random image">
    <div>overlay 2</div>
  </li>
  <li class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=3" alt="random image">
    <div>overlay 3</div>
  </li>
  <li class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=4" alt="random image">
    <div>overlay 4</div>
  </li>
  <li class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=5" alt="random image">
    <div>overlay 5</div>
  </li>
  <li class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=6" alt="random image">
    <div>overlay 6</div>
  </li>
  <li class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=7" alt="random image">
    <div>overlay 7</div>
  </li>
  <li class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=8" alt="random image">
    <div>overlay 8</div>
  </li>
  <li class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=9" alt="random image">
    <div>overlay 9</div>
  </li>
  <li class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=10" alt="random image">
    <div>overlay 10</div>
  </li>
  <li class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=11" alt="random image">
    <div>overlay 11</div>
  </li>
  <li class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=12" alt="random image">
    <div>overlay 12</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've seen `.image > div` similar syntax used before, what does it mean? I couldn't find relevant information on the net.

Comment: @Zhenya `.image > div` will only target `<div>` if it is an immediate child. Consider this `<div class="image"><div class="outer"><div class="inner">...</div></div></div>` -- if you wrote css selector like `.image div` it would target both .outer and .inner. But `.image > div` will only target .outer

Comment: that is very interesting information thank you for answers.

Comment: If you want to center with position absolute you can use this `position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` this will place the text in the middle horizontal and vertical like in my grid example. Glad you got it working though!

Comment: @Zhenya I added a bunch of styling to have some fun on hover, maybe some useful tips there for you as well

Answer (score 1):

@Simp4Code
I've ended up going with `positioning`, it ended up working better with existing code.

```css
.gallery-container {
  border: 2px black solid;
}

.gallery {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.gallery li {
  max-width: 40%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em 0.5em;
  max-width: 90%;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.image-name {
  position: absolute;
  color: ivory;
  background-color: rgb(94, 88, 94);
  opacity: 0;
}

.image:hover .image-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-container">
  <ul class="gallery">
    <li class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=1" alt="random image">
      <div class="image-name">one</div>
    </li>
    <li class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=2" alt="random image">
      <div class="image-name">two</div>
    </li>
    <li class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=3" alt="random image">
      <div class="image-name">three</div>
    </li>
    <li class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=4" alt="random image">
      <div class="image-name">four</div>
    </li>
    <li class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=5" alt="random image">
      <div class="image-name">five</div>
    </li>
    <li class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=6" alt="random image">
      <div class="image-name">six</div>
    </li>
    <li class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=7" alt="random image">
      <div class="image-name">seven</div>
    </li>
    <li class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=8" alt="random image">
      <div class="image-name">eight</div>
    </li>
    <li class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=9" alt="random image">
      <div class="image-name">nine</div>
    </li>
    <li class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=10" alt="random image">
      <div class="image-name">ten</div>
    </li>
    <li class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=11" alt="random image">
      <div class="image-name">eleven</div>
    </li>
    <li class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=12" alt="random image">
      <div class="image-name">twelve</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good, I've edited this answer into a snippet so your final solution can be easily seen -- it will be visible once it's been approved

Comment: a bit late, but here's a huge thank you!!